# Using collection_select for Searching In Active Record - Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have only used collection_select once to populate a country id on an associated model User.  Now I would like to do a search of User using the same collection_select statement on another view and list the Users for a selected country.  My attempts have failed.  I can look at the link after a country is selected and see that the id for the country is selected.  But when I click my submit button the collection_select statement resets the selected value to the default selected value and ignores the value selected.  For example when I select the country of France, the id is 75.  When I select France and click Search by Country the id shows up like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/users_admin?utf8=✓&query=&user%5Bcountry_id%5D=75
```

Here is the form where I have the collection_select statement.  I copied the statement that I am successfully using when I add/update a record on the User model with the selected country_id.  What I want my logic to do is when I select a country and click Search by Country that the selected country remains selected in the drop down list and the User records with the selected country_id are displayed on the screen.  The Search by Name works as expected.

```
<%= form_tag users_admin_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <p style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search for first, last or full name" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span valign="center"><%= submit_tag "Search by Name", class: "btn btn-medium btn-custom", :name => nil %></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= collection_select(:user, :country_id, Country.order('name'), :id, :name, {:selected => 233}) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span valign="center"><%= submit_tag "Search by Country", class: "btn btn-medium btn-custom", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code in my controller.

```
def users_admin
  case
  when User.where("active_user = ?", '1').count > 0 # blocked users exist
    @users = User.where("active_user = ?", '1').all
  when params[:commit]=='Search by Country'
    @users = User.where("country_id = ?", params[:country_id]).all
  else
    @users = User.text_search(params[:query])
  end 
  @microposts = Micropost.all
end
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with how the collection_select statement is coded or another logic problem.  My first thought was that I need to somehow save the selected value from the collection_select statement then use it in my where clause.  But I do not know how to recode the statement to do that and also have the default selected value as 233 which is the United States when the screen is first displayed.  I also thought that maybe I should have two different forms instead of one.  I just do not know the direction I should go at this point.

I have searched mainly Stack Overflow for questions regarding this issue.  The questions related to collection_select for the most part were relating to uses that are way past what I will probably ever use it for.  Again I have only used the collection_statement once:)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

collection_select should be used when you are working with a model in your form (i.e. when you use `form_for @user do`, not `form_tag`

Try something like this:

```
<%= select_tag :country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :title, params[:country_id]), include_blank: true %>
```

The `params[:country_id]` parameter there makes sure that whatever country_id is passed in via the GET request will be selected in your dropdown after the user submits your search form.

btw, `form_for` is used when there is a model involved (being created/updated). If you're creating a search form, this isn't the case and you should be using `form_tag`

Read this for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: I wondered if I had to make two separate forms.  The one that I was working with is using the form_for.  I will do what you suggest and try again.  That is a new command for me.  Thanks so much.

Comment: The code you included above is using `form_tag` :) Let us know how it works out, and remember to mark this answer if it works.

Comment: The code suggested works where now when someone selects a country it will keep the selected country selected when they click Select A Country.  Now I need to figure out how to display the User records for the selected ID.  It looks like it is completely ignoring the when clause when it checks the commit.  When I check the test.log file I see where it checks the first when clause and skips it, which it should from my test data.  Then it goes to the else clause apparently without checking my params[:commit] clause.  I also changed it to use params[:submit] but got the same results.

Comment: @LightBeCorp Your usage of case/when is a bit strange, but then again I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. Your when statements seem to be pretty independent of each other, so is it not possible that the first when is true and your subsequent whens are never even evaluated?

Comment: That is what I am trying to check.  I want them independent where only one of them will execute.  The when clauses are in the order on how I want them executed.  After my last response I tried to do the params[:commit] clause first but got the same result.  There appears to be something with how I have that clause written that I just cannot see at the moment.  The other two clauses work.  Looks like a needle in a haystack search at this point :)

Comment: @LightBeCorp Ah I see what you mean. And you're sure that params[:commit] is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I have checked the text in my params[:commit] to make sure it matches what is in my code. You can see this also in my original post. I also tried params[:submit] because I was not sure if you check different things for form_tag (new to me) and form_for. At this point I am convinced the problem is with the params[:commit] but I do not know what it is at this point. I just added some code to display a value when it hits each clause of my case statement. The params[:commit] clause is not being evaluated like the other two. Believe me when this is fixed I will scream the answer here LOL

Answer (score 0):

After doing more searching I decided to display params on my view just to see what was in the hash.  I did not have commit in my submit_tag so I changed to check to see if params[:country_id] was present.  I was able to get the country search working with the modified code:

```
case
  when User.where("active_user = ?", '1').count > 0 # blocked users exist
    @users = User.where("active_user = ?", '1').all
  when params[:country_id].present?
    @users = User.where("country_id = ?", params[:country_id].to_i).all
  else
    @users = User.text_search(params[:query])
end
```

The only problem I have left (minor issue) is that in order to get the name search working properly after a country search the person has to select the blank entry in the country list.  Other than that this is solved.  It should not take long to figure out how to wipe out the value in params[:country_id].  Either that or I may do an implicit check for params[:query].present? . Thanks for your help.  Another pair of eyes did help indeed.